# False value with loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a tool to execute the command `host` for multiples IP ranges.
These IP ranges are located in a file in the same folder as my script.

I can read my file with the IP, I can create my threads, but the code execute `i` not like in a loop (as a variable):

> Host 10.123.204.{i} not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Here is my code:

```
import threading
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from itertools import product
import subprocess


def check_host(host: str):
    subprocess.run(["host", host])
    #status = 'up' if return_code == 0 else 'down'
    #print(f'{host} : is {status}')


def start_threads(addr_range):
    for addr in addr_range:
        t = threading.Thread(target=check_host, args=(addr,), 
                             name=f'Thread:{addr}')
        t.start()
        yield t


def ping_network_range(net_class: str):
    myFile=open('../findRoute/ip.txt', 'r')
    net_class = net_class.upper()
    for line in myFile:
        if net_class == 'A':
            newLine=line+''
            newLine=newLine[:-1]
            threads = list(start_threads(f''+newLine+'.{i}' for i in range(256)))#here is the error
        elif net_class == 'B':#TBD
            threads = list(start_threads(f'127.0.{i}.{j}' 
                                        for i, j in product(range(256), range(256))))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Wrong network class name {net_class}')

    for t in threads:
        t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Host network addresses by network class')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--nclass', choices=('A', 'B'), 
                        required=True, help='Choose class A or B')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ping_network_range(args.nclass)
```

Comment: Add `f` before the `.{i}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't properly making use of f-strings. You have the first empty string as an f-string, then don't make the string that you want to format an f-string.

Instead of:

```
f''+newLine+'.{i}'
```

You meant:

```
f'{newLine}.{i}'
```

Note how it uses one string (not multiple concatenated), and everything that should be substituted is in `{}`s.